# Densify only selected features in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3

How can I densify only selected features. checkbox is grayed out for this in QGIS 3.8.1:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-select the Input Layer, and you should see the Selected Features Only checkbox become active again. I just tested locally, and it works fine, but only after a re-select of the Input Layer.